# socket bind returns same ephemeral port

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

I'm trying to bind 256 different sockets in 256 different `pthread`'s to different ports by passing `0` port value to socket `bind` function. But sometimes same port gets bound to different sockets. I found this issue from debug output. Can somebody explain why this is happening. This is my sample code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

unsigned short get_sock_name(int sock_fd) {
    socklen_t sock_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    struct sockaddr_in recv_IP_sock_addr;
    getsockname(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&recv_IP_sock_addr, &sock_len);

    return (ntohs(recv_IP_sock_addr.sin_port));
}
    
void* run(void *t) {
    int sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);;
    struct sockaddr_in recv_IP_sock_addr;
    memset((char*)&recv_IP_sock_addr, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    recv_IP_sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    recv_IP_sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    recv_IP_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(0);
    
    int yes = 1;
    setsockopt(sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&yes, sizeof(yes));
    
    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&recv_IP_sock_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    
    unsigned short port = get_sock_name(sock_fd);
    
    printf("receiving data from port %hu\n", port);
    
    char buff[2048];
    while (1) {
        ssize_t len = recvfrom(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t pt_arr[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        pthread_create(&pt_arr[i], NULL, run, NULL);
        
    char buff[32];
    fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin);
}
```

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of bind for error.

Comment: @stark I'm not getting any bind error. For simplicity reason I've removed the error checking part.

Comment: Nope. If you get the same port then some of your bind calls are returning EADDRINUSE

Comment: @stark In my actual code I'm checking the return value of `bind` and its `0` for all the socket `bind` function calls.

Comment: So you make an outrageous claim that bind doesn't work based on code that you won't show?

Comment: @stark the code that I've posted reproducing the issue that I'm facing in my actual code. You can give a try by running it on your machine.

Comment: I tried your code. It gets no duplicate ports.

Comment: @stark Turn up the number of threads from 256 to 2560.

Comment: bind failed: Bad file descriptor

Comment: @stark Right, but did any two of your threads get the same port? Oh, nevermind, you may not have enough file descriptors to get duplicate ephemeral ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `SO_REUSEADDR` which, for UDP, permits two sockets to bind to the same port. This is needed for multicast. Using it with unicast UDP doesn't seem to be a particularly good idea. Using it when letting the implementation select the port doesn't seem like a good idea either.

Get rid of `SO_REUSEADDR` as it makes no sense and causes pathological behavior with UDP unicast.